# SQL subquery trying to find entries of main table by matching with sub table

Tags: sql

Please help me in resolving below query. Table A has EMP_NO (pk) , EMP_NAME and Table B has EMP_NO (not unique), EMP_REPORTEE , Need to query Table A info where EMP_REPORTEE does not have "CLERK"
example:
TABLE A

```
EMP_NO EMP_NAME
100    VICTOR
200    JOHN
300    AASIF
```

TABLE B

```
EMP_NO  EMP_REPORTEE
100     MANAGER
100     OPERATOR
200     OPERATOR
200     CLERK
300     MANAGER
300     CLERK
```

Resultant query must have EMP_NO 100

I tried to write subquery like below

```
SELECT EMP_NO, EMP_NAME
FROM TABLE A,
     TABLE B
WHERE A.EMP_NO = B.EMP_NO AND
      B.REPORTEE != 'CLERK'
```

Comment: SQL means "structured query language" of which there are a number of varieties depending on the DBMS.  Please be more specific.

Comment: I need a generic solution, I am from Mainframe DB2 background

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result - i.e. a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can chekc with a correlated subquery and EXISTS if one employee is a not a clerk

```
SELECT t1."EMP_NO", t1. "EMP_NAME" FROM TableA t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
  FROM TableB t2 WHERE t2."EMP_NO" = t1."EMP_NO" AND t2. "EMP_REPORTEE" = 'CLERK')
```